# Reading CSV timestamp strings into AmCharts aren't converted from strings to integers

Tags: csv, graphing, amcharts5

I am attempting to evaluate the AmCharts charting package using one of their examples. My data is a simple CSV file with 3 air quality values , then a UNIX timestamp (to the seconds), and then another UNIX timestamp value with three extra zeros because AmCharts docs state they expect timestamps to the millisecond.
Now, the data gets loaded from the file on the server and parsed into an array, but the values for the UNIX timestamp are a string. The AmCharts documentation has all kinds of info about processing a date-time string and turning it into an epoch time, but what about when the value is already in UNIX time?
The data loads, as I stated, and the chart container forms with no error, but no x-axis values or graph of data
[Here is link to the html/js](https://br1.nic.edu/amchart/index.html)

[Here is the link to the CSV data file](https://br1.nic.edu/amchart/DataSheetTEST.csv)
Since I am not a paid subscriber to their libraries (yet), they provide no direct support and recommend posting here.

Adding a debugging breakpoint at line 247 in the linked index.html, I can see that the data variable ("data1") is loaded with the parsed data from the CSV file. The yAxis seems to get setup as expected, but the xAxis (dates/timestamps) is not valid and there is no graph of the data (alos no error(s) reported in console.